# Can I say "-igiĝi" or "-iĝigi"?

Tags: word-usage, word-formation

For example:

> Ĝi ruĝigiĝis / It got turned red

> Li/Ŝi/Ri/Ĝi sidiĝigis / They got sat down

Maybe these frases are a little complicated and unnecesary, but I feel they are still interesting and could convey a useful distiction.

What do you think?

1. Are they useful and good?
2. Are they correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambaŭ estus ĝustaj, sed la [principo de neceso kaj sufiĉo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neceso_kaj_sufi%C4%89o) limigas la situaciojn, kie oni tion uzus.

Pri `-iĝig-` vi povas legi [tion ĉi](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj_frazroloj/ig.html#j-zos). Resume: tiuj konstruoj estas tre maloftaj. En la situacioj kiam oni povus ili uzi, estas preferinde uzi `igi`.

```
Kaj Li ŝanceliĝigas ilin kiel ebriuloj
```

preferinde:

```
Kaj Li igas ilin ŝanceliĝi kiel ebriuloj
```

La alian formon, `-igiĝ-`, mi neniam renkontis. Kaj mi ne povas pensi kial, semantike, iu bezonus kunmeti la du tiel sinsekve.

Notu ke `ligi` ne estas kunmetaĵo kun `-ig-` kaj `manĝigi` ne estas kunmetaĵo kun `-iĝ-`, do ili ne estas konsideritaj.

Comment: "La alian formon, -igiĝ-, mi neniam renkontis. Kaj mi ne povas pensi kial, semantike, iu bezonus kunmeti la du tiel sinsekve." Mi pensas, ke ĝi ja povas esti utila, efektive pli utila ol -iĝig-. Ekz-e "Ili forigiĝis" estas utila ĉar ĝi estas pli simpla maniero diri "Oni ilin forigis". Sed eble estas tro malfacile kompreni ĝin, kaj kial ne nur simple uzi la duan eblon. Ĉu tio estas kion vi diras?

Comment: "Ili forigiĝis" ne estas komprenebla, por mi. Eĉ leginte la klarigon. Ne ĉiuj kunmetaĵoj produktas ion uzeblan. Ĉu vi konas [tekstaro.com](https://tekstaro.com)? Tie vi povas serĉi en amaso de elektitaj esperantaj tekstoj, ĉu io aperas, kaj en kiu kunteksto. [Tiu ĉi serĉo](https://tekstaro.com/?s=61bf70e55f094) rezultos ĉiujn aperojn de `igiĝ`. El tie restas du uzoj (post rapida rigardo kaj forigo de nur ŝajnaj `-ig-` kunmetaĵoj): `ridigiĝis` (mistajpo de `rigidiĝis`) kaj `amikigiĝis`, kiun mi ne komprenas (ĉu simpla `amikiĝis`?).

Comment: Interese, jes! Mi supozas, ke ili ja estas malfacile kompreneblaj. Pri amikigiĝis, mi pensas, ke ĝi signifas, ke oni igis ilin amikiĝi, do ne estas samkiel amikiĝis. Sed mi samopinias ke estas pli bonaj manieroj :-)

Comment: Ho, pardonu. En la teksto, ŝajnas ke ja estu amikiĝis simple.